# isMomentary on SegmentedPickerStyle Swiftui

Tags: swiftui, picker, segmentedcontrol

Trying to set `isMomentary` of `Picker` `SegmentedPickerStyle` in **SwiftUI**.

`UIKit` `UISegmentedControl` has a Bool `isMomentary`.

Looking for how to achieve the same for **SwiftUI**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of how I handle it. Basically you have your picker set its selection back to whatever default value you want it to be. In this example I have a segmented picker with 5x options from 2 -> 50 miles. I can perform an action after a selection that corresponds to that selection; After which it will return to its default state. You can add a delay or animation to this to make it a bit smoother, but that's outside the scope of this question.

```
@State var selectedRange = 2
//someView {...

                    Picker(selection: selectedRange, label: Text("Search Radius")) {
                        Text("2 miles").tag(0)
                        Text("5 miles").tag(1)
                        Text("10 miles").tag(2)
                        Text("25 miles").tag(3)
                        Text("50 miles").tag(4)
                    }
                    .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                    .onChange(of: selectedRange, perform: { value in
                        doAction()
                    })
```

#### Function

I actually have mine inside of a ViewModel but in this example it's on the view itself. Just be sure to check scope and put it in the right place.

```
func doAction() {
    //Do whatever you need to have done.
    switch selectedRange {
        case 0:
            //Do Something.
        default:
            //Do Something
    }
    selectedRange = 2
}
```

Comment: I tried that approach only trying to avoid as user would have to deselect and re-select on that segment should they wish to perform the action of that segment. ill upvote tough as is a solution. thank you

Comment: You’re missing a binding somewhere if it’s doing that. Notice that in my example I’ve set the range back to 2 after the action is complete. That should update the UI back to its position. It may need to be in a DispatchQueue

Comment: Came back here to complete the solution setting the State selectedRange to one higher than available has made it momentary. So in accepted answers case with 5 options (0...4). I set the State var selectedRange = 5 and  in the onChange modifier I set selectedRange to 5. Which doesn't exist resulting in no selection/ momentary